# Should we pronounce "Macedonia" with a hard k?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, greek

I know that many words loaned from Greek to English have gone through a transition from a hard-k kappa to a soft sibilant sound. For example, English "cybernetics" comes from Greek "κυβερνητικός". I know that this can even happen for names, like with Latin "Caesar" (pronounced like "kaiser") becoming Spanish "César". Does this also apply to Macedonia, which is still spelled with a kappa ("Μακεδονία") and has people living there today?

Comment: Greek words have generally gone through a Latin or Romance filter and are thus pronounced more according to those languages' rules. That's still an oversimplification. Basically, the words were brought in generally in a learned context and pronounced according to English conventions, not the conventions of the source language.

Comment: There is now the problem that there are two Macedonias, which speak different languages. In the Republic of North Macedonia, they speak Macedonian, which is македонски јазик  [maˈkɛdɔnski ˈjazik], with a /k/, not an /s/. Indeed, the /k/ is stressed: _ma KED on ski_. It's a Slavic language, not Greek. In Greek, it's also pronounced with a /k/, though I think the stress is different.  A Greek or (North) Macedonian might correct you if you use an /s/.

Answer (score 5):

With issues like this the "correct" pronunciation is based on usage, and to a lesser extent your desire to have people understand you.

"Macedonia" is pretty much always pronounced in English with a soft C (that's true of both the geographical entities with that name). If you want to maximize the number of people who understand you, and be thought of as pronouncing correctly, then you should too. If you wish to start a pronunciation revolution feel free to start using a hard C.

Proper nouns do not always have to be pronounced in line with the etymology of the word they are based on. The adjective "celtic" is pronounced with a hard C. The major sports teams with the word in the title all use a soft C. The inconsistency is fairly irrelevant and unlikely to be changed any time soon.

Comment: When I hear the hard "c" I usually think of modern politics, but the soft "c" make me think of the region or ancient history. Celtic though I usually think of with a hard "c", except for the soccer club. An Australian view.

Comment: Interesting. In the US there's a basketball team called the "Celtics", with an /s/, not a /k/. _Celtic_ with a /k/ refers to a kind of cultural artifact, like Celtic dancing or Celtic languages.